# trying to append row google sheets api

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to get the append row example to work for a couple of hours now with no luck, I'm getting no errors but my spreadsheet isn't getting updated at all.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing#append_values

```
function insertInSpreadSheet(sheetId, sheetService) {
var body = {
    "range": "Sheet1",
    majorDimension: "ROWS",
    "values": [
        ["Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date"],
        ["Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016"],
        ["Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016"],
        ["Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016"],
        ["Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)"]
    ]
}

var params = {
    spreadsheetId: sheetId,
    "range": "Sheet1",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    media: {
        body: body  
    }
};
sheetService.spreadsheets.values.append(params, function(err, res) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(res);
    return;
});
}//end function
```

Response:

```
{ 
    spreadsheetId: '1NvBbTlET7G5yhuuFF6zj-7LQUQ9TI85_geviRLuzCD0',
    updates: { 
        spreadsheetId: '1NvBbTlET7G5yhuuFF6zj-7LQUQ9TI85_geviRLuzCD0',
        updatedRange: 'Sheet1!A1' 
    } 
}
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit**

My Spreadsheet is completely empty

Comment: That looks like the response for an update, not for an append. It might be that the node.js client is mistakenly calling the wrong HTTP method. Are you sure you're calling `sheetService.spreadsheets.values.*append*`?  Can you trace the actual HTTP methods this results in?  If so, what is it?

Comment: yeah i did nothing is wrong with the client

Comment: What HTTP URLs does your code result in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is how I do it and it works fine for me.*

//Write rows TO sheet

```
const { name, email, phone, city, pin, nick } = req.body;

await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    range: "test1!A:E",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {
         values: [
             [name, email, phone, city, pin, nick]
         ],

    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The Node.js client library expects the body of the request in a parameter called `resource`. See the following example:

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  range: 'Sheet1',
  valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  resource: body,
}, function (err, response) {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers didn't quite work for me...

```
  // file comes from drive.files.list
  // sheet comes from sheets.spreadsheets.get
  const rows = [['1','2',3/* , ... */]]; 
  const request = {
    spreadsheetId: file.id,

    range: sheet.title,  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',

    insertDataOption: 'INSERT_ROWS',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    resource: {
      values: rows
    }
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, function (err, response) {
   // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Only difference I see is the example includes a range for the sheet which you're updating:

```
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:E1",
```

Comment: Sounds good when you are trying to update the row from A1 to E1.
But I think the goal is to append data (at the bottom of the already existent data), so it's ok to use `A:E` when defining the range.

Answer (score 1):

For Google API v4 formatting your request as such should work:

```
requests.push({
appendCells: {
  sheetId: 2063764471,
  fields: '*',
  rows: [{
    values: [{ // First Row
      userEnteredValue: {stringValue: "first row"}
    }, {
      userEnteredValue: {numberValue: 2}
    }, {
      userEnteredValue: {numberValue: 3}
    }]
  }]
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the updated googleapis client for Node.js, the resource property has been renamed to `requestBody`.

```js
const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
  valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
  requestBody: {
    values: [
      ['Justin', '1/1/2001', 'Website'],
      ['Node.js', '2018-03-14', 'Fun'],
    ],
  },
});
```

Link to the sample from googleapi's doc: [Append sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/sheets/append.js)