# Google sheets api v4 post not appending data to spreadsheet

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I am using the nodejs module to try and add data to a google spreadsheet follows using the [append method](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append):

```
    function addEventData(auth) {
      var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
      sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
        auth: auth,
        spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
        range: 'Sheet1!A:B',
        valueInputOption:'USER_ENTERED',
        insertDataOption:'INSERT_ROWS',
        alt:'json'
      },
      {
        values:[['xoxo', '12']]
      },
      function(err, response){
        if(err){
          console.log('The api returned an error:'+err);
          return
        }
        console.log(response);

      })
    }
```

The response returned is as follows:

```
   {
      spreadsheetId: '{spreadsheetId}',
      tableRange: 'Sheet1!A1:B18',
      updates: 
       { spreadsheetId: '{spreadsheetId}',
         updatedRange: 'Sheet1!A19' } 
    }
```

Whereas i would expect a response like:

```
{
  "spreadsheetId": "{spreadsheetId}",
  "tableRange": "Sheet1!A1:B17",
  "updates": {
    "spreadsheetId": "{spreadsheetId}",
    "updatedRange": "Sheet1!A18:B18",
    "updatedRows": 1,
    "updatedColumns": 2,
    "updatedCells": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realised I was passing the the body to the options instead of using the resource field, thanks to responses to this question:

[trying to append row google sheets api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502346/trying-to-append-row-google-sheets-api?rq=1)

```
function addEventData(auth) {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.append({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: 'Sheet1!A:B',
    valueInputOption:'RAW',
    insertDataOption:'INSERT_ROWS',
    alt:'json',
    resource:{
      values:[['xoxo', '12']]
    }
  },

  function(err, response){
    if(err){
      console.log('The api returned an error:'+err);
      return
    }
    console.log(response);

  })
}
```

Comment: if you have solved your problem yourself, please mark this answer anccepted so that it's clear that the problem is solved. Best regards